# rxjs reduce does not continue

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I have the following setup in an angular 7 application:

```
@Effect({dispatch:false})
LoadInstances$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(fromAppAction.AppActionTypes.LoadInstances),
take(1), // <-- solved my problem
switchMap((action: fromAppAction.LoadInstances) =>
      this.entityService.GetInstances()
    ),

switchMap(instances=>from(instances)), // flatten the array to single values
flatMap( // combine the instance with its UserData
    (inst)=>this.entityService.GetCurrentUserInfo().pipe(take(1)),
    (inst,usr)=>({...inst, UserData:usr})
),
flatMap(
  (inst)=>this.entityService.GetUserPersonalSettings(inst.id).pipe(take(1)),
  (inst,settings)=>({...inst, Settings:settings})
),
tap(result=>console.log('before reduce:',result)), // <-- this gets called 3 times (I have 3 instances)
reduce<Instance>((a, c) => [...a, c], []), // accumulate all results to one array
tap(result=>console.log('instances: ', result)), // <-- this gets never called
...
```

in essence, i have an array of instances, flatten them out, call GetCurrentUserInfo and GetUserPersonalSettings for each instance, add the result as a property to the instance and then want to accumulate them back to an Instance[].

This works so far, only that the reduce function does not continue. I know that this is because one of the other observables do not complete. But how can that be?
The initial from(instances) iterates over the array and should finish then, yes? And the calls to GetPersonalSettings are just plain httpClient.get() calls that according to the documentation are single value observables that finish after a successful call.

Can anybody help me?

[Edit]
scan is not an option here, since I need the complete array of instances to continue with.
[Edit2] toArray has the same issue as reduce, it only issues the result if the former Observable(s?) complete.

**Anyway**: I do not want to change this setup since it works basically. I only want to understand which Observable is not completing and why. This will solve my issue.

Comment: if have tried scan, it will produce an output for every item in the instances array, like so:
[inst1]
[inst1, inst2]
[inst1, inst2, inst3]
But i want only the complete result array with _all_ instances in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not **continue**"? Do you get one result from `tap(result=>console.log('instances: ', result))`, or none at all?

Comment: no, the last tap is never called, only the 'before reduce'

Comment: Reduce keeps taking in items, until the observable completes. Is it clear when your observables completes?

Comment: That is exactly my question! In my understanding all the observables do complete, but obviously not and I don´t understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I learned about operator [toArray](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/toArray), might simplify your code.
You stream doesn't complete because stream before first `switchMap` is not completed

```
/* What is here? Probably still open stream? */
switchMap((action: fromAppAction.LoadInstances) =>
  this.entityService.GetInstances()
),
```

Quick try would be put `first()` or `take(1)` before first `switchMap`

Comment: I thought that switchMap would unsubscribe the former observable and start something completely new in the chain. Is that not true?

This is actually an ngrx effect. I have edited my first post to show the code lines before switchMap.

ToArray has the same issue as reduce, it only issues a value if the observable is finished, but the big question in my case is: Which observable does not finish?

Comment: Your code looks fine for me, in your case you are using `take(1)`, so it doesn't matter if you have `switchMap` or `mergeMap`, is defines strategy how to merge an inner stream events if there are more events in an outer stream. Try to add `catchError` at the end, maybe you have a error in one of GetBlaBla methods. I created similar example and it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-esfjjy?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: I had added the take(1) in the code but somehow not compiled. It works now. Thank you all, especially Maksim.